# WebView отображает пустую страницу

Tags: android, webview

Есть приложение, которое с помощью WebView выводит преобразованный через XSLT XML.

```
html = ImfxTools.transformXslt(xslt, xml);
webView.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Переменная `html` после преобразования содержит в себе примерно следующее:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru" xml:lang="ru"><head><title>Протокол обработки</title><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/><style>* {font: 10pt/12pt Trebuchet MS}

body {background: #eee}
h1 {text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold; font-size: 120%}
table {margin-bottom: 10px}
table td {padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: top}

.bold {font-weight: bold}
.lpd10 {padding-left: 10px}
.lpd20 {padding-left: 20px}
.center {text-align: center}
.w25 {width: 25%}
.w33 {width: 33%}
.w50 {width: 50%}
.w100 {width: 100%}

.bgw {background: white}
.bgg {background: #eee}

.border {border: solid 1px #999}</style></head><body><h1>
          Протокол обработки
        </h1><table><tr><td>Код документа</td><td class="bold">2</td></tr><tr><td>Номер декларанта</td><td class="bold">385</td></tr><tr><td>ID документа</td><td class="bold">1</td></tr><tr><td>Время изменения</td><td class="bold">05.12.2018 19:17:57</td></tr><tr><td>Результат обработки</td><td class="bold">Принято</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

До недавнего времени все это замечательно работало, но с какого-то момента WebView просто перестал выводить данные, отображая одно лишь пустое окно (см. скриншот ниже). Никаких изменений в код приложения не вносилось. В 5 версии Android все по-прежнему нормально работает.

Подскажите, как можно восстановить работоспособность приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так пробовали:  `webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8")` ?
или так: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html,"text/html","utf-8",""); `

Comment: методом тыка удалось восстановить работоспособность так `loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null)` но суть проблемы так и осталась неясной. Можете оформить в виде ответа, я отмечу правильным.

Comment: добавил ответ, то что я понял из разных источников

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод **loadData** загружает данные используя схему URL "**data:**". Для этого необходимо использовать стандартное шестнадцатеричное кодирование символов (например: '#', '%', '\', '?' следует заменить на %23, %25, %27, %3f).

Пример из https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

```
// Create an unencoded HTML string
// then convert the unencoded HTML string into bytes, encode
// it with Base64, and load the data.
String unencodedHtml = "&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;'%23' is the percent code for ‘#‘ &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;";
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
myWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

Плюс есть ограничение: JavaScript запущенный на странице, загруженный с помощью этого метода, не сможет получить доступ к содержимому, загруженному с использованием любой другой схемы, кроме "**data:**", включая "http(s):".

Метод **loadDataWithBaseURL** с базовым URL "**data:**" будет аналогичным методу **loadData**, *но если базовый URL-адрес использует любую другую схему, данные будут загружены в WebView в виде простой строки, и нет необходимости в кодировании*.

Кроме того контент, может обращаться к файлам локальных устройств (через URL-адреса схемы "**file:**").

Поэтому для загрузки локального контента желательно использовать **loadDataWithBaseURL**.

Дополнительно: насколько помню, раньше срабатывал еще такой трюк:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
myWebView.loadData(data, mime, encoding);
```